# WP error connecting to DB

Tags: sql, wordpress

I get this message when I try to access my [site](http://sodabrasil.com). 
The site was working properly, and I tried to add google analytics... 
Anyway, sodabrasil was a site created out of WP. 
sodabrasil.com/paskin was WP. 
We did the integration of logins. Everything was working. 
When I run http://sodabrasil.com/dbtest.php, it says it's connected. 
this is the debug code.

```
<?php
//connect to MySQL Server
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "******");
if (!$conn)
  {
    die(mysql_error());
  }
else
  {
    echo "1. Successfully connected to MySQL database server.<br /><br />";
  }
// select database
$db_sel = mysql_select_db('*********', $conn);
if (!$db_sel)
  {
    die ('cant\'t use database: ' . mysql_error());
  }
else
  {
    echo "2. WordPress database selected. <br />";
  }
?>
```

the database  *****   is the DB sodabrasil uses for the login. 
But accessing sodabrasil is blocked even before the login!!!

I am not a professional coder, which makes things a lot harder.

This is the real config file:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
//echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//die;
//require_once('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');



require_once('/home/houswe5/public_html/sodabrasil.com/paskin/wp-blog-header.php'); 
global $mysqli;
$server = 'localhost'; // The host you want to connect to.
$username = '****'; // The database username.
$password = '*****'; // The database password. 
$database = '*******'; // The database name.
$dbms = 'MySQL 5';
$dbport = '3306';
//$dbh = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to SQL server");
//$my_db = @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;die;
}
// If you are connecting via TCP/IP rather than a UNIX socket remember to add the port number as a parameter.
?>
```

Exact same credentials. 
But this url (http://sodabrasil.com/db_connect.php) throws the error message in regards to DB.

Thank you for you help.

G.

Comment: I've had this issue numerous times when installing WP, usually a reinstall fixes it. 

This is a stupid question, but have you actually visually verified that the connection string stored in WP is the same one that is used to run your test script there?

Comment: That's the default wp error when your database credentials in wp-config.php are not correct. Check those and make sure they are correct. The code you posted is probably not even being reached cause wp is killing the process before it gets there

Comment: I have checked hundreds of times... site has been working for months... the integration is one week old, but it was working for a few days very well. Debug and real config files have the same credentials.

Comment: sodabrasil was not WP before the login integration with the blog. Now they are connected, but they have different DB for the login. It was working...